# Samsung CLP-325W Wireless Printing, not sure what address it's getting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, printing

I have a Samsung CLP-325W wireless printer, and I don't have the MAC address bounded to a static IP address. The printer is turned on and its wireless light is blue. However, from the view of my router, it doesn't seem to be on the network.

The printer is binded to the SSID and has worked before, but when it gets turned off it seems to forget about the network.

Is there anyway that I can force the printer to print out it's current state? [IP address etc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201112/20111222102855370/EN/en/english/start_here.htm), it looks like you can:

> In ready mode, press and hold the Cancel () button for about 5
>   seconds. You can find your machine’s MAC address and IP address.